# Refer to system dependent / user paths like "AppData" or "MyDocuments"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, user-profile

What i'am trying to figure out is , how do i refer to a path which changes from system to system. An example:

```
System A:

C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming

System B:

C:\Users\User2\AppData\Roaming
```

Basically i'm trying to figure out how to deal when the user profile changes. How do i refer to a file/folder in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current user's profile path from the APPDATA environment variable.

```
os.environ["APPDATA"] # returns "c:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Roaming"
```